# Why can't I log in to a remote desktop?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I am given a live ip from my office which can be accessed from home. However I have problem I can see my remote dektop login screen but I am not able to log in even though I provide the correct password. Can anybody tell me what is missing?

I read [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Why-can-t-I-connect-using-Remote-Desktop-Connection) that is supposed to solve this problem.

But, in that the point which says "I can't log on to the remote computer". In that point the article mentions to add my home computer to local users and groups. What does it mean by that? If you think there is some other problem then also let me know your views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply means you don't have permission using your current credentials.

1. Try including the office domain in the username. The syntax would be like `DOMAIN\Username`.
2. Contact your office to get you proper credentials that work, make sure that they set the permissions.

Comment: You're the man. I bow to you. You don't know how important it was for me to access the remote machine. DOMAIN\Username did the trick :-). I wish I could give you all my points.